# how to clear null values apache superset

Tags: apache-superset

I'm making some dashboards in superset apache, but I have the problem that it makes me null when it doesn't find values to add and this is annoying for the view, for the client. I can't find an option that suppresses the null values or in any case that puts zero.

thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1):

David example is great! but if you don't want to miss those counts, you could do a calculated column where null values go to a 0 label

```
case when my_col is Null then 0 else my_col end
```

Comment: there are no null values, Superset with the Breakdowns property
puts a slash for each existing attribute, if the SQL has no values it auto-completes it with null. the SQL does not return any null

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do that by adding a custom WHERE clause in order to remove null and 0 values from the display.
[image: custom where clause]

Comment: there are no null values, Superset with the Breakdowns property
puts a slash for each existing attribute, if the SQL has no values it auto-completes it with null. the SQL does not return any null